# 3D gizmo to faces and verts selected?

Tags: 3d-view, gizmo

I have recently moved over to Blender and I am currently learning the new workflow.

I saw a video of someone selecting some verts in Blender and like Maya the gizmo automatically went over to the selected verts. I can't find anything instructing how to make the gizmos act this way. Does anyone happen to know the answer where they select verts and the gizmo follows?

Comment: if you have selected the Move, Rotate or Scale tool in the Tool bar on the left, the gizmo should come where you have selected some vertices

Comment: Note that location of gizmo depends on selected `Transform Pivot Point` option. If it's `active element` you'll have gizmo over last selected vertex, if it's `median point` than gizmo shows up at geometric center of selection, when it's `3D cursor` gizmo is at 3D cursor, etc

Answer (score 1):

As moonboot say, simply tick move,rotate,scale as you prefer under the show Gizmo button (located on the upper part of the 3D viewport window, on the left of the viewport shading option)[image]